# Creating Database Mail with T-SQL returns "principal name is not valid"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, database-mail

Configuring Database Mail is so long.

So I want to create a script that automatically create it for me

```
DECLARE @YourEmail NVARCHAR(50) SET @YourEmail = 'MyEmail@mydomain.com' --Put here your E-mail
DECLARE @YourPassword NVARCHAR(50) SET @YourPassword = 'MyPassword' --Put here your E-mail
DECLARE @YourSMTPSserver NVARCHAR(50) SET @YourSMTPSserver = 'MySMTPserver' --Put here your SMTP Server
DECLARE @YourPort int SET @YourPort = '25' --Put here your SMTP port

-- Create a Database Mail account  
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
    @account_name = 'SQL_Spring_Cleaning_Account',  
    @description = 'Mail account for SQL_Spring_Cleaning.',  
    @email_address = @YourEmail,  
    @replyto_address = @YourEmail,
    @display_name = 'SQL_Spring_Cleaning Mailer',  
    @mailserver_name = @YourSMTPSserver, 
    @port = @YourPort,
    @use_default_credentials = 0,
    @username = @YourEmail,
    @password = @YourPassword;


-- Create a Database Mail profile  
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'SQL_Spring_Cleaning_Profile',  
    @description = 'Profile used for SQL_Spring_Cleaning mail.' ; 

-- Add the account to the profile  
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp  
    @profile_name = 'SQL_Spring_Cleaning_Profile',  
    @account_name = 'SQL_Spring_Cleaning_Account',  
    @sequence_number =1 ; 

-- Grant access to the profile to the DBMailUsers role  
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'SQL_Spring_Cleaning_Profile',  
    @principal_name = 'ASPIRES3\franc',  
    @is_default = 0 ;
```

But unfortunately SSMS returns me:

```
Msg 14607, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sysmail_verify_principal_sp, Line 49 [Batch Start Line 0]
principal name is not valid
```

The error is obviously on line

```
@principal_name = 'ASPIRES3\franc',
```

but I don't understand what is wrong with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the name you're using a user in the msdb database?

> [ @principal_name = ] 'principal_name'
>   The name of the database user or role in the msdb database for the association. principal_name is sysname, with a default of NULL. Either principal_id or principal_name must be specified. A principal_name of 'public' makes this profile a public profile, granting access to all principals in the database.

Comment: Using a role name doesn't work. That is a role created with `create role`.